# How to make real time visit page

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I want to make a real time visit page which take data from database. I use a repeater for this which binds from a dataset. It works fine, but when new row added, I want to show some effect like in Feedjit's "real time visits" page.

I used jquery for this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.FadeIn').click(function () {
          $('.show').show('slow');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".FadeIn").trigger('click')
});
```

But it doesn't work. It slides down the whole repeater. Should I use something other than repeater or it is a jQuery problem?

Comment: read my question first dont be so rude you are not only the webmaster i only think that you tell me where to start working with signalR. dont comment about my country

Comment: @CodeCaster Please don't comment about country. Each one over here is to help and help each other. You are not the one who have built up this community.

Comment: I want real time update with long pulling and signalr. i am new to this. can long pulling be done by simple jquery or javascript,

Comment: @CodeCaster I agree on that, but pointing that its from India or any other country, is really not acceptable. It was really rude and I haven't seen such statement in stackoverflow till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use long pulling with comet or SignalR 
SignalR is the best options for Real time updates.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple technologies which you can use, also you can try exploiting Timeout function of Jquery

Few links to check

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/315938/Real-time-Asynchronous-Web-Pages-using-jTable-Sign

<del>http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-aspnet-signalr</del>

http://datatables.net/

Updated Link for SignalR:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr-20

Comment: I probably wouldnt user the database to find out how many people are online, I would count the number of active sessions where users are logged in.

Comment: I use database because i have to fetch information about users which is stored in database. but real problam is that when a new row is added it should be show slide down effect like feedjit live page updates

Comment: Take a look on above links, I am not saying it will sort your issue but will give you an idea on how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks @Nipun these links realy help me